# Google Maps V3 MarkerCluster plugin by polygon coordinate boundaries

Tags: google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement markercluster v3 in my map. I am able to get it to work, but am trying to cluster the markers based on specific neighborhoods and regions. I have created a layer on my map from a kml file that is seperated into several neighborhoods and I'd like the map markers to "cluster" by the neighborhood that they're located in. I tried messing with

http://jsfromhell.com/math/is-point-in-poly#example-header

but have had no luck...

Another question led me to figure out that I should use this method:

containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)

Has anyone been able to achieve this?

Here's an example of a site that does it:

apartmentlist.com

Thanks for any help!